# Neural Network Error Rate Does Not Progress

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, pybrain

Neural networking noob here.
I am using PyBrain to try and create a network that learns music.
My dataset consists of about a hundred songs where the input for the network is two notes and the target is the next two notes.
Each note is represented by an int for the note/chord combination, an int for octave of the note and a float for the duration of the note.
My network looks like this:

```
    net = RecurrentNetwork()
    net.addInputModule(LinearLayer(6, name='in'))
    net.addModule(LSTMLayer(50, name='hidden1'))
    net.addModule(LSTMLayer(50, name='hidden2'))
    net.addOutputModule(LinearLayer(6, name='out'))
    net.addConnection(FullConnection(net['in'], net['hidden1'], name='c1'))
    net.addConnection(FullConnection(net['hidden1'], net['hidden2'], name='c3'))
    net.addRecurrentConnection(FullConnection(net['hidden2'], net['hidden1'], name='c4'))
    net.addConnection(FullConnection(net['hidden2'], net['out'], name='c5'))
    net.sortModules()
```

With a dataset and trainer like so:

```
ds = SupervisedDataSet(6, 6)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds, verbose = True, momentum = 0.01)
```

My problem is, when I train the network, I get a huge error back (E.G. 24569847209.8) which never seems to go down, it changes with each epoch but it always hovers around the same number.

After the network is trained it creates a song by taking two random notes as input, then generating the target, then passing the target back as an input, and repeating this over and over until it has a full song. But I find all it ever does is just write output over and over again, like it just learns one fixed target.

I'm really not sure what's wrong with what I have that is causing this.If there is some information I should include please let me know.

Comment: Stackoverflow is rather for solving coding problems than to teach people how to use neural networks. A lot of things can go wrong when initializing the network. Until you really have coding problems ask https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks or https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36247/how-to-get-started-with-neural-networks

Comment: I don't think I agree with that evaluation.
I have code; there is a problem with it.
I have edited my question and title to clear up any confusion.
If you feel I have left out something important, let me know.

Comment: It might be that your network just doesn't know what to do, because there are so many combinations of two notes hidden in the songs. You could try to "overtrain" your network with just a few very similar songs. In that case the network will not guess but learn / remember the sequence and you should see if your approach works in general.

Comment: @Joe ran it on just one song (about 1,000 or so samples of note pairs) for 1,000 epochs. Total error: 5660650926.69 at the start and Total error: 5563442152.03 at the end. The result was the same - the same two notes over and over again. I will try training even more but it seems to me like the error shouldn't be that high in the first place, seems like a ridiculous number?

Comment: To me it seems that your network is just not doing what you think it does. Maybe start with a very simple example, maybe take an array of 50 numbers with maybe 5 or so sines or cosines and make your network guess them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the learning problem! 
My network error is now steadily decreasing as I train it!
I was using the wrong trainer. As I am using a recurrent neural network, I should not have been using the back propagation trainer. I am now using the RPropMinusTrainer.
To fix, the following line:

```
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds, verbose = True, momentum = 0.01)
```

Was changed to

```
trainer = RPropMinusTrainer(net, dataset=ds, verbose = True)
```